# XmlText attribute in base class breakes serialization

Tags: .net, serialization, xml-serialization

I have a base class with a property called Name, which has an XmlText attribute.

When an inherited class is serialized I get an exception saying:

> There was an error reflecting type
>   '[type name]'. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Cannot serialize object of type '[type
>   name]'. Base type '[base type name]'
>   has simpleContent and can only be
>   extended by adding XmlAttribute
>   elements. Please consider changing
>   XmlText member of the base class to
>   string array.

Here are my class definitions, the error occures when serializing to xml.

```
[Serializable]
public class LookupItem
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute()]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlText()]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Vendor : LookupItem
{
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Vendors : List<Vendor>
{

}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems to happen because the `LookupItem` class has no child element in its XML representation. Because of that, `XmlSerializer` considers it to be an [simpleContent](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_simpleContent.asp) XML element. If you add a new property to `LookupItem`, which is to be serialized as an XML element, it works fine.

I just spent a few minutes looking at the available XML serialization attributes, but I couldn't find any which would allow to specify that the type is NOT a `simpleContent` element...

So I think you could make it work by adding a dummy property or field that you never use in the `LookupItem` class. If you're never assign a value to it, it will remain null and will not be serialized, but it will prevent your class from being treated as `simpleContent`. I know it's a dirty workaround, but I see no other easy way...

```
public class LookupItem
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute()]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlText()]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public object _dummy;
}
```

(BTW, note that the `Serializable` attribute is not necessary for XML serialization.)

Anyway, do you really need to serialize `Name` as XML text ? That's quite uncommon, usually XML elements have either simple content (text), or child elements... A mix of both makes the XML harder to read, so unless you are compelled to do that, I suggest you serialize `Name` as an attribute or child element.